# How to program a recurrence relation with a sum and combination involved?

Tags: matlab, relation, recurrence

I am trying to use MATLAB in order to solve a problem.
The recurrence relation is something like this:

‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ f(1,r,N) = (0.5)^N * NCr

[image: picture]

So, this is the function I made:

```
function [ f ] = fxprb(n,r,g)
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here

if n==1
    f=(0.5^g)*nchoosek(g,r)
else
    i=1:g-1
    x=fxprb(n-1,i,g);
    f=nchoosek(g,r)*sum(x.*((i/N)^r)*((1-i/N)^r));
end

end
```

I don't know how to code, and I'm stuck. `f(1,0,3)` works fine but when `n` is bigger than two, I am not getting results at all, instead I get an error message like this:

> ??? Error using ==> `nchoosek` at 24
>
> The second input has to be a non-negative integer.
>
> Error in ==> fxprb at 6
>
> `f=(0.5^g)*nchoosek(g,r);`
>
> Error in ==> `fxprb` at 9
>
>     `x=fxprb(n-1,i,g);`

Can you help me out?

Comment: I take it `NCr` means binomial coefficient? And `k==i==n`? And `g==N`? And the function takes three arguments, not two as in the image. And, you have an exponent `r` in the last term in your code, and `N-r` in the image, which one is correct? ...to be frank, sloppiness is probably one of the problems here...

Answer (score 0):

By passing the argument `i = 1:g-1` to `fxprb()` in the recursive call, you are assuming that `nchoosek()` produces multiple outputs for vector input.

It does not.

So, you'll just have to loop:

```
function f = fxprb(n,r,N)

    if n==1
        f = (0.5^N) * nchoosek(N,r);

    else

        f = 0;
        for k = 1:N-1
            f = f + fxprb(n-1,k,N) * (k/N)^r * (1 - k/N)^(N-r) ;
        end

        f = f * nchoosek(N,r);

    end

end
```

Comment: I love you so much. You are my savior. And I'm not exaggerating at all.

Comment: @min You would think you could at least give your savior an accept. ;) http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers